# Convert string to list within list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I currently have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[ {'id': 'ABBA', 'num': '10 3 5 1'}, {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': '4 5 6 20'}]
```

How can I change the value associated with the num key from a string to a list and iterate that over the list of dictionaries? Like this:

```
[ {'id': 'ABBA', 'num': ['10','3','5','1']}, {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': ['4', '5', '6' '20']}]
```

I know there are similar questions out there on how to loop through a list of dictionaries and changing a string to a list, but I can't seem to put all of these together.

I've tried:

```
for i in list_of_dictionaries:
    for id, num in i.items():
        for val in num:
            val = val.split()
            print(val)
print(list_of_dictionaries)
```

But I get `[]` for val and then the same unchanged list of dictionaries back.

Comment: are those really **list of dictionaries**???

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made a mistake when typing the simplified example. It should read [{stuff},{stuff}] and there should be brackets around the numbers to denote a list of what I want to get: num: ['10','3','5','1']. *edited* Is that better? I can post the actual code but it's lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the snippet

```
a=[ {'id': 'ABBA', 'num': '10 3 5 1'}, {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': '4 5 6 20'}]
for i in a:
    i['num']=i['num'].split(' ')
```

```
#[{'id': 'ABBA', 'num': ['10', '3', '5', '1']}, {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': ['4', '5', '6', '20']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
for i in list_of_dictionaries:
    val = i['num'].split()
    print(val)
    i['num'] = val
print(list_of_dictionaries)
```

By the way notice that string keys for dictionaries should be inside quotes.

As you can see updating the value of `i['num']` when you are iterating over `list_of_dictionaries` with i variable, changes the main list. So you don't need to create a new list and append new items each time.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I am new to Python and still not used to the syntax.